# Open default Email Client

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, mailto, thunderbird

I've been all day trying to find code that would allow me to launch the default email system with an attachment but I did not succeed. My app is written in python, and runs on windows. I did not succed with python with this post [Python: launch default mail client on the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779191/python-launch-default-mail-client-on-the-system) so, I tried with C# with this Post [Open default mail client along with a attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328598/open-default-mail-client-along-with-a-attachment) and some other information I found on the Internet. In this post the following line of code:

```
var mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { filestream });
```

raises an Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

I found the solution with Start-Process mailto:... and it opens the default email system with the attachment argument ignored, this is the code I use here:

```
C:\SomeDir> Start-Process "mailto:some.guy@someplace.com?subject=an email&body=see attachment&attachment='cost example.xlsx'"
```

The default email System is Thunderbird if that matters. I will keep searching for a solution. Any idea is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What does this mean 'but the attachment argument does not seem to work'? Do you get an error? Can you share your current code?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer I edited the question. I read after that mailto utility does not support attachment.

Comment: ok, but your shared link to C# looks like a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328598/open-default-mail-client-along-with-a-attachment

Comment: May be I was not able to make it running, I'll try again. If you can help me with that code on the post I mentioned, I'll give you 100 USD.

Comment: Use the full path to the file. Even then it is up to the e-mail client if it wants to parse the protocol elements that way...